# Sync only a single bookmarks folder

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

There seem to be a few options for syncing Firefox bookmarks, such as [Firefox Sync](https://account.services.mozilla.com/) and [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/). **Are there any other services which might allow the user to sync only a single bookmark folder between computers?** I would like this situation:

```
// Home computer bookmarks

+ Animals
  How to pet a rat
  How to feed a snake

+ Film
  The Opry House

+ Shared
  SuperUser.com


// Work computer bookmarks

+ Python
  PEP8 reference
  GIL reference

+ Shared
  SuperUser.com
```

Firefox Sync has the limitation that one must sync **all** their bookmarks, i.e. the entire bookmarks feature will be identical on all synced computers. Thus, I cannot leave the `Animals` folder only at home and the `Python` folder only at work.

Xmarks has the limitation that all folders must be uploaded to the server. Thus, the server will have the `Animals`, `Python`, and `Shared` folders and I can select which folders to download to which computer. This would not be a problem if I had a reasonable amount of bookmarks. However, I happen to have about 40,000 bookmarks at home and syncing them is beyond all reason. No, I cannot purge them: they are there for a reason!

**Does there exist a Firefox addon that will let the user select only certain folders for syncing?**

**Edit:** There exist many bookmarks on the home computer that I don't want to sync to an external server. For purpose of discussion, let's assume some material which is legal where I reside but not legal where Xmarks servers are (such as links to download [The Opry House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Opry_House) which is out of copyright in most of the world, but still protected IP in the US).

Comment: Why not just sync them all? 40k won't take up much space. Are there some you just don't want to have at work..., or a restriction on having work bookmarks on a home machine? Once you have done the first one, sync is incremental.

Comment: @RoryAlsop +1 Plus, as the OP has already mentioned, Xmarks has options to handle the "restrictions against work bookmarks on a home machine" bit.

Comment: My own Firefox bookmarks take up 655 lines when exported to HTML. Some of that is metadata, but the average line-to-bookmark ratio is very close to 1:1. (Yeah, I've accrued a lot and just never bothered to clean. BTW: I also use Xmarks with zero problems.) The HTML file is only 108 KB. Breaking that out, we get roughly 165 bytes per bookmark. Scale that up, and your 40,000 bookmarks are probably taking up around 6 MB of space (more or less - probably less). This is pretty easy to sync once, and keeping it synced afterwards is trivial with incremental updates.

Comment: Thank you, I do see that the question should have been asked on the software recommendation SE site. [Here it is.](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/firefox-addto-to-sync-only-a-single-bookmarks-folder)